# Selenium WebDriver IE11: JavaScript error

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using WebDriver to help with regression testing of an Oracle Portal webapp, I have tried to get my test scripts functioning with IE11 but have not had any success.

I understand IEDriverServer.exe does not currently support  WebDriver and the issue requires cooperation from Microsoft, I have tried the steps outlined in responses to Selenium issue #6511.

1. Protected mode settings are the same for all zones
2. Enhanced Protected Mode is disabled.

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
@Test
public void Ts_Advertisement_disti() throws Exception {
    launchURL(url);
    LoginCheck("ts_Advertisement_disti");
    // Check the Continue and Accept button for user
    checkContinueAndAcceptButton();
    // write out the title of the page in console
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    assertEquals("Home", driver.getTitle());
    assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'advertisement-holder')]")));
    System.out.println("Element is present");
    assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//img[contains(@id,'ad_image')]")));
    System.out.println("Element is present");
    // Verify img <a> navigates to location
    String follow_url = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'advertisement-holder')]/a")).getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println(follow_url);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    // Follow advertisement and verify not on landing page
    driver.get(follow_url);
    assertNotEquals("Home", driver.getTitle());
    driver.navigate().back();
```

Here is the output from TestNG:

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Received a JavaScript error attempting to click on the element using synthetic events. We are assuming this is because the element isn't displayed, but it may be due to other problems with executing JavaScript. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I would be grateful for any input on a resolution to this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Which line throws this exception?

Comment: can you also paste the code for **checkContinueAndAcceptButton();** method?
I'm assuming this is causing the synthetic event - since all others appear to just find elements and assert isElementPresent.